# Result source SharePoint 2013 version

Tags: search-results, result-source

I just would like to know if it is possible to add Result Sources in SharePoint 2013-Standard Edition?
Merci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Result Sources are supported for Standard Edition.

In order to configure it, Please check this Technet Article

[Configure result sources for search in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683115.aspx)